# Fortran, Finalization at (1) is not yet implemented

Tags: oop, fortran, gfortran, finalizer, fortran2003

I am trying to implement a simple finalizer, but I can't get even [this example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf121.aix.doc/language_ref/typeboundprocedures.html) to compile:

```
  MODULE m
   TYPE :: t1
    REAL a,b
   END TYPE
   TYPE, EXTENDS(t1) :: t2
    REAL,POINTER :: c(:),d(:)
    CONTAINS
    FINAL :: t2f
   END TYPE
   TYPE, EXTENDS(t2) :: t3
    REAL,POINTER :: e
    CONTAINS
    FINAL :: t3f
   END TYPE

   CONTAINS
   SUBROUTINE t2f(x) ! Finalizer for TYPE(t2)'s extra components
    TYPE(t2) :: x

    print *, 'entering t2f'  
    IF (ASSOCIATED(x%c)) then
     print *, ' c allocated, cleaning up'
     DEALLOCATE(x%c)
    end if 
    IF (ASSOCIATED(x%d)) then 
     print *, ' d allocated, cleaning up'
     DEALLOCATE(x%d)
    end if  
   END SUBROUTINE
   SUBROUTINE t3f(y) ! Finalizer for TYPE(t3)'s extra components
    TYPE(t3) :: y

    print *, 'entering t3f'
    IF (ASSOCIATED(y%e)) then
      print *, ' e allocated, cleanup up'
      DEALLOCATE(y%e)
    end if 
   END SUBROUTINE
END MODULE
```

using GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7) gives me this error output:

> $ gfortran -c
>   m_example.f03 m_example.f03:5.26:
>
> TYPE, EXTENDS(t1) :: t2
>                             1 Error: Finalization at (1) is not yet implemented m_example.f03:10.26:
>
> TYPE, EXTENDS(t2) :: t3
>                             1 Error: Finalization at (1) is not yet implemented

Is this a bug, does it mean that finalizers are not yet implemented in gfortran, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just thought to look at the GCC Wiki, and finalizers are not implemented until version 4.9.

Comment: To add to @RDM's comment: If all goes well, [gcc 4.9 should release around 22nd April](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2014-04/msg00089.html).

Comment: You can also use the development snapshots, the release candidate RC0 is already available. You have to compile it yourself, though.

Answer (score 2):

Since gcc 4.9, finalizers are recognized. Furthermore, if you do not implement them yourself, the compiler appears to generate finalization code itself.

Which unfortunately leads to [bug 59765](http://dannyvanpoucke.be/ca-coders-anonymous/). Still available in gcc gfortran 4.10, as I was unfortunate to discover.